# How to put buttons on GtkDrawingArea?

Tags: c, gtk, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using GTK+ 2.0 and SDL 2 and I need GtkDrawingArea to render SDL on my GTK window. And I use GtkFixed to put GtkDrawingArea on my window.

However, when I try to put a GtkButton using GtkFixed, I can't see any buttons on my drawing area. Is there any example code that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't place widgets on top of other widgets using GTK+ 2.0.

You could use GtkOverlay if you were using [GTK+ 3.0](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Overlay.html) or [GTK+ 4.0](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Overlay.html) but I [can't find](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/index.html) something like this in older version.

(And BTW, I'd advise to take the time and understand [GtkBox](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkBox.html), [GtkTable](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTable.html) and [GtkLayout](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkLayout.html). GtkFixed is a pain to work with in longer perspective)